# what is the easiest way to convert NetCDF to HDF5 on windows

Tags: hdf5, netcdf

In this [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetCDF) it is written that

> NetCDF users can create HDF5 files

But I had troubles finding how to actually do this conversion. The only thing I was able to find is http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF-FAQ.html#convnetcdf . Here it is written that:

> There is a Windows executable called ncdf2hdf from Fortner Software
>   (defunct) that does the conversion. It is no longer available, but may
>   be found by searching the web. However, the HDF files that it
>   generates have been reported to lack some of the structure that is
>   found in the ones produced by the route above.

I should not mention here that it is really hard to find this ncdf2hdf on the web.

Up till now I have found that I can use python to read netcdf file with http://gfesuite.noaa.gov/developer/netCDFPythonInterface.html or https://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/ but is there an easier way.

Comment: People often try the other way around, so usual boring question on your question: why do you want to do that? HDF faq link explains all you need to do the conversion. Don't forget that they are talking about different versions of same program `ncdump/ncgen` which they rename to `hdf_ncgen` for their version

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/netcdf4-python/ is perfect for that task, but you can also use unidata's netcdf command line utilities or a bit more advanced nco operators utilities and do about anything with netcdf data. If you wanted to do conversion just to be able to use pytables for some reason, think twice as also with any conversion between NetCDF and HDF you'll loose metadata descriptions, which will make your data worse to handle.

Comment: yep, I know, that's the right tool if you want to interface netcdf from Python

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, see which netCDF format your file is using. If you have netCDF installed on your system, the easiest way to do this is to use ncdump:

```
ncdump -k foo.nc
```

If ncdump returns `netCDF-4`, or `netCDF-4  classic  model`, then congratulations, you already have an HDF file, as netCDF-4 is the netCDF data model implemented using HDF5 as the storage layer. These files can be ready by the HDF library version 1.8 or later, and from what I can tell, pytables.

If ncdump returns `classic` or `64-bit offset`, then you are using netCDF-3 and will need to convert to netCDF-4 (and thus HDF). The good news is that if you have netCDF installed, you can do the conversion pretty easily:

```
nccopy -k 4 foo3.nc foo4c.nc
```

See the [netCDF FAQ](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/faq.html) for more details, specifically [this](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/faq.html#fv13) entry.

That said, it's well worth the time to learn how to use netCDF-4-python to do this task without the intermediate conversion (don't let the name fool you, netCDF-4-python can read the netCDF-3 format, as well as most netCDF-4 files). netCDF-3 is still widely used, even outside of the meteorological community, and this extra hoop will become a hassle after a bit. More importantly, if the size of your file is very large, the conversion can become quite time consuming.